# tabulate using tabyl by grouping variable using group_split and group_map

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, purrr, janitor

To get a quick frequency (tabulate) of one column or multiple columns at the one time I use `tabyl` function like so:

```
library(janitor)
library(tidyverse)

#tabulate one column at a time
iris %>% 
  tabyl(Petal.Width)

#tabulate multiple columns at once using map
iris %>% 
  select(Petal.Width, Petal.Length) %>% 
  map(tabyl)
```

I'm trying to replicate these two cases but have the output by a grouping variable, `Species` in this example. I would like the simplest solution and I would like to try the newer `group_split` and `group_map` commands for this.

I have been able to produce a similar type output in a dataframe format (although a simple list that `tabyl` produces is what I want for the case of more than one variable):

```
#works 
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(out = map(data, ~ tabyl(.x$Petal.Width) %>% 
                     as_tibble)) %>% 
  select(-data) %>%
  unnest
```

This works but I would have thought it could be a bit more simple like my column method approach, I was thinking something like this for one column per grouping variable:

```
#by group for one column
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map(~tabyl(Petal.Width))
```

For multiple columns I'm not sure I need the select row here? Maybe group_map could simplify it in one line?

```
#by group for multiple columns
iris %>% 
  #do i need to select grouping variable and variables of interest?
  select(Species, Petal.Width, Petal.Length) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map(~tabyl())   #could I use group_map and select the columns at once?
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  iris %>% 
       #use split(.$Species) if you need a list with names 
       group_split(Species) %>% 
       map(~imap(.x %>%select(Species, Petal.Width, Petal.Length), 
                  function(x,y){
                          out <-tabyl(x)
                          colnames(out)[1]=y
                          out}))
```

If you jsut need the default column name for the first column, then you can do `iris %>% group_split(Species) %>% map(~map(.x, tabyl))`

Comment: thanks, copying your idea, this is probably the shortest way to get multiple variables `iris %>% 
  split(.$Species) %>% 
  map(~map(.x %>% select(Petal.Width, Petal.Length), tabyl))`

Comment: I also like this way but not sure how to preserve names after flattening: `iris %>% 
  split(.$Species) %>% 
  map(~select(., Petal.Width, Petal.Length)) %>% 
  flatten() %>% 
  map(tabyl)`

Comment: @user63230 since yesterday I can't see your final goal, so here the best guess I have `iris %>% split(.$Species) %>% map(~select(., Petal.Width, Petal.Length)) %>%unlist(recursive = F) %>% map_df(tabyl, .id = 'id') %>% mutate(Species=gsub('(^[^.]+)\\.(.*)','\\1',id), Variable=gsub('(^[^.]+)\\.(.*)','\\2',id))`